# Centering <ul> tag

Tags: html, css, html-lists, gallery, centering

I can't get this unordered list gallery to center up in the page. I've tried all sorts of suggestions from sof&google but I still can't get it right. Plz help. Thanks!

Here is the CSS that i wrote.

```css
#galleryArea {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#gallery {
  list-style: none;
}
#gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 250px;
  max-height: 250px;
}
#gallery li {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0 1.6%;
  text-align: center;
}
#gallery a {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="galleryArea">
    <ul id="gallery">
      <a href="#">
        <li>
          <img src="img/img.png" />
          <p>Desc...</p>
        </li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li>
          <img src="img/img.png" />
          <p>Desc...</p>
        </li>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="clearFloat">
        <li>
          <img src="img/img.png" />
          <p>Desc...</p>
        </li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li>
          <img src="img/img.png" />
          <p>Desc...</p>
        </li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li>
          <img src="img/img.png" />
          <p>Desc...</p>
        </li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li>
          <img src="img/img.png" />
          <p>Desc...</p>
        </li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: can you please put this into a js fiddle? it'd help get your question answered more quickly.

Comment: Your HTML is a mess. You got a bunch of rogue links inside the `ul`.

Comment: Why do people down vote questions like this?

Comment: And why do people post comments that say they are too bored to answer something? Stating that you are bored with someone's question seems (a) pretentious, (b) condescending, and (c) ludicrously unconstructive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this:

```
#galleryArea {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

By this:

```
#galleryArea {
    display: block;
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eaf64k4a/)

Comment: It works, but would you care to explain why `margin: 0 auto` doesn't work in this case?

Comment: `margin: 0 auto` is equivalent to `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` both applied at the same time. In your case you need only `margin-left` to center the _ul_. Adding `margin-right` messes it up. Therefore I specified only `margin-left`

Comment: I know it is the same, but usually I see [`margin: 0 auto` for centering a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/horizontally-center-a-div-in-a-div), so I wondered why it messes things up now.

Comment: @GolezTrol I guess thats due to the `display: inline-block;` css property thats partially doing some centering of its own when applied :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fiddle (click image)
[image: JSFiddle]

Remember to clear floats.

```
#gallery:after {
    clear: both;
}
#gallery:before, #gallery:after {
    content: ' ';
    display: table;
}
```

To center something, you should declare a width on a block element and set it's left and right margin to auto: `margin: 0 auto;`

```
#galleryArea {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
}
#gallery {
    list-style-type: none;
    background: #bada55; 
}
```

In the html, you should place the `<a>` tags inside the `<li>'s` and not around them.

```
<div id="galleryArea">
    <ul id="gallery">
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="img/img.png" />
                <p>Desc...</p>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="img/img.png" />
                <p>Desc...</p>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="img/img.png" />
                <p>Desc...</p>
            </a>
        </li>        
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="img/img.png" />
                <p>Desc...</p>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="img/img.png" />
                <p>Desc...</p>
            </a>
        </li>        
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the the trick... I hope you like grumpy cat :P

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7s2xbmc1/)

Screenshot:

[image]

//HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet">>
</head>
<body>
<section id="gallery">
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://cdn.bleedingcool.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/too_good_for_grumpy_cat.jpg"/>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.</p>
    </div> 
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://cdn.bleedingcool.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/too_good_for_grumpy_cat.jpg"/>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.</p>
    </div> 
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://cdn.bleedingcool.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/too_good_for_grumpy_cat.jpg"/>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.</p>
    </div> 
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://cdn.bleedingcool.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/too_good_for_grumpy_cat.jpg"/>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.</p>
    </div> 
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://cdn.bleedingcool.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/too_good_for_grumpy_cat.jpg"/>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.</p>
    </div> 
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://cdn.bleedingcool.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/too_good_for_grumpy_cat.jpg"/>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.</p>
    </div> 
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://cdn.bleedingcool.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/too_good_for_grumpy_cat.jpg"/>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.</p>
    </div> 
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://cdn.bleedingcool.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/too_good_for_grumpy_cat.jpg"/>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.</p>
    </div> 
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://cdn.bleedingcool.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/too_good_for_grumpy_cat.jpg"/>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.</p>
    </div> 
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://cdn.bleedingcool.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/too_good_for_grumpy_cat.jpg"/>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.</p>
    </div> 
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://cdn.bleedingcool.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/too_good_for_grumpy_cat.jpg"/>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.</p>
    </div> 
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://cdn.bleedingcool.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/too_good_for_grumpy_cat.jpg"/>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.</p>
    </div> 
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

//CSS

```
body{
    margin: 0 !important;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}   
#gallery{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto;

    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;

    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

}
.item {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;

    min-width: 300px;
    max-width: 300px;   

    margin: 5px;
    padding: 10px;

    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;

    background: #ccc;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.item:hover{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40);
}
img{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-algin-self: center;
    align-self: center;


    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;

    border: 2px solid black;

    max-width: 250px;
    max-height: 141px;
}
p{
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign an specific width to the gallery div and asign equal margin-right and margin-left values.

Try:

```
#galleryArea
{
  width:80%;
  margin-right:10%;
  margin-left:10%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my tip:

CSS:

```
#galleryArea {
    text-align: center;
}

#gallery {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style:none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 90%;
}

#gallery img {
    height: auto;
    max-height: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    width: 100%;
}

#gallery li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 1.6%;
    text-align: center;
    width: 21.8%;
}

#gallery a {
    color: black;
    display: block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="galleryArea">
        <ul id="gallery">
            <li><a href="#">
                <img src="img.png">
                <p>Desc...</p>
            </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">
                <img src="img.png">
                <p>Desc...</p>
            </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">
                <img src="img.png">
                <p>Desc...</p>
            </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">
                <img src="img.png">
                <p>Desc...</p>
            </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">
                <img src="img.png">
                <p>Desc...</p>
            </a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/k34ps7vt/

Btw... that "margin: 0 auto" in your code does not work, because the "#galleryArea" is styled as inline-block. Try to change it to block.

Btw #2: Your code is not valid. You need to have an "A" to be inside "LI".

Answer (score 0):

Centered images and centered text beneath every images fixed!

```css
#galleryArea {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 90%;
  margin-left: 10% ;
  margin-right: 10% ;
}

#gallery {
    list-style:none;
}

#gallery img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 250px;
    max-height: 250px;
}

#gallery li {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    margin: 0 1.6%;
}

#gallery a {
    color: black;
}
#gallery a,p {
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="galleryArea">
    <ul id="gallery">
        <li><a href="#">
            <img src="img/img.png" />
            <p>Desc...</p>
        </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">
            <img src="img/img.png" />
            <p>Desc...</p>
        </a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="clearFloat">
            <img src="img/img.png" />
            <p>Desc...</p>
        </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">
            <img src="img/img.png" />
            <p>Desc...</p>
        </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">
            <img src="img/img.png" />
            <p>Desc...</p>
        </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">
            <img src="img/img.png" />
            <p>Desc...</p>
        </a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
```